# C++ Error "expected unqualified-id '(' token" before debugging

Tags: c++

So I am trying to start debugging what is wrong with my code but I am currently having an issue with an error that I don't really understand. I am using Code Blocks through Oracle Virtual Machine. I am pretty sure the problem lies in the header of my code but I'll post the whole thing.

I am trying to build a Siri like program that uses header files, prototypes, and functions. So far I only have basic math working.

Error Messege reads:
||=== Build: Debug in JARVIS (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
/home/user/Dropbox/Lecture36CompilationAndMemory/JARVIS/JARVIS.h|1|error: expected unqualified-id before ‘)’ token|
||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "JARVIS.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string command;
    bool jarvis_running = false;
    cout << "J.A.R.V.I.S" << endl;
    cout << "Give a command from the list of commands available." << endl;
    cin >> command;

    if (command == "-h")
    {
        jarvis_running = true;
        cout << "The available commands are: math" << endl;
    }

    if (command = "math")
    {
        jarvis_running = true;
        math();
    }

    if (jarvis_running == false)
    {
        cout << "That command was not valid" << endl;
        cout << "Type '-h' if you need to know the available commands." << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

*JarvisFunctions.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "JARVIS.h"

using namespace std;

int math()
{
    char mathCommand;

    cout << "(A)ddition, (S)ubtraction, (M)ultiplication, or (D)ivision?" << endl;
    cin >> mathCommand;

    if (mathCommand == "A")
    {
        cout << "input the two integers you are adding" << endl;
        cin >> integer1 >> integer2;

        math.setValues(integer1, integer2);
        addition add;
    }


    else if(mathCommand == "S")
    {
        cout << "input the two integers you are subtracting" << endl;
        cin >> integer1 >> integer2;

        math.setValues(integer1, integer2);
        subtraction sub;
    }

    else if(mathCommand == "M")
    {
        cout << "input the two integers you are multiplying" << endl;
        cin >> integer1 >> integer2;

        math.setValue(integer1, integer2);
        mulitplication multi;
    }

    else if(mathCommand == "D")
    {
        cout << "input the two integers you are dividing" << endl;
        cin >> integer1 >> integer2;

        math.setValues(integer1, integer2);
        division div;
    }

    else
    {
        cout << "you did not input the right fuctions, either use A, S, M, or D" << endl;
    }
}
```

header

JARVIS.h

```
    #ifndef JARVIS_H
    #define JARVIS_H

    int math();

    class math
    {
        private:
        int val1;
        int val2;

        public:

        math()
        {
            cout<<"calling math constructor"<<endl;
        }

        void setValues (int a, int b){
            val1 = a;
            val2 = b;
        }

        ~math()
        {
            cout<<"calling math deconstructor"<<endl;   
        }

    };

    int addition:public math
    {
        finalVal = val1 + val2;
        return finalVal;
    };

    int subtraction:public math
    {
        finalVal = val1 - val2;
        return finalVal;
    };

    int multiplication:public math
    {
        int finalVal = val1 * val2;
        return finalVal;
    };

    int division:public math
    {
        int finalVal = val1 / val2;
        return finalVal;
    };

    #endif  //JARVIS_H
```

Comment: This question will be perceived a lot better if you give us the exact scenario and error message, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of misconceptions in what you have. You really should spend more time with whatever resources you're learning from.

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "JARVIS.h"

int main()
{
    std::string command;
    bool jarvis_running = false;
    std::cout << "J.A.R.V.I.S" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Give a command from the list of commands available." << std::endl;
    std::cin >> command;

    if (command == "-h")
    {
        jarvis_running = true;
        std::cout << "The available commands are: math" << std::endl;
    }

    if (command == "math")
    {
        jarvis_running = true;
        int result = math();
        std::cout << "result = " << result << std::endl;
    }

    if (jarvis_running == false)
    {
        std::cout << "That command was not valid" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Type '-h' if you need to know the available commands." << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

JARVIS.h

```
#ifndef JARVIS_H
#define JARVIS_H

#include <iostream>

int math();

class Math
{
    private:
    int val1;
    int val2;

    public:

    Math()
    {
        std::cout<<"calling math constructor"<<std::endl;
    }

    void setValues (int a, int b){
        val1 = a;
        val2 = b;
    }

    ~Math()
    {
        std::cout<<"calling math deconstructor"<<std::endl;
    }


    int addition()
    {
        int finalVal = val1 + val2;
        return finalVal;
    }

    int subtraction()
    {
        int finalVal = val1 - val2;
        return finalVal;
    }

    int multiplication()
    {
        int finalVal = val1 * val2;
        return finalVal;
    }

    int division()
    {
        int finalVal = val1 / val2;
        return finalVal;
    }

};

#endif  //JARVIS_H
```

JarvisFunctions.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "JARVIS.h"

int math()
{
    std::string mathCommand;

    std::cout << "(A)ddition, (S)ubtraction, (M)ultiplication, or (D)ivision?" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> mathCommand;

    int integer1, integer2;

    // create an instance of Math class
    Math m;
    if (mathCommand == "A")
    {
        std::cout << "input the two integers you are adding" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> integer1 >> integer2;

        m.setValues(integer1, integer2);
        return m.addition();;
    }


    else if(mathCommand == "S")
    {
        std::cout << "input the two integers you are subtracting" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> integer1 >> integer2;

        m.setValues(integer1, integer2);
        return m.subtraction();
    }

    else if(mathCommand == "M")
    {
        std::cout << "input the two integers you are multiplying" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> integer1 >> integer2;

        m.setValues(integer1, integer2);
        return m.multiplication();
    }

    else if(mathCommand == "D")
    {
        std::cout << "input the two integers you are dividing" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> integer1 >> integer2;

        m.setValues(integer1, integer2);
        return m.division();
    }

    else
    {
        // TODO: add some sort of error handling
        std::cout << "you did not input the right fuctions, either use A, S, M, or D" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

}
```